# sql datetime in sas date format

Tags: sql, sas, format

```
    proc sql noprint;

%let today=%sysfunc(today(),yymmdd10.);
%put &today.;

  select
        COALESCE(sum(abc.step_sum),0)
      into :SumLoans_12m
    from
        RTDM_ABT.ABT_CONTRACT abc
        where abc.CLIENT_ID = "&T_CLIENT_ID"
        and abc.CONTRACT_BEGINDATE - &today. <= 360   
        and abc.DML_FLAG NE 1; 
quit;
```

I understand it is necessary to convert `CONTRACT_BEGINDATE` (2021-01-14 00:00: 00.000) to format SAS, I think it would help , how do you do that? Thanks for your help!

```
ERROR:
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable TODAY resolves to 2021-05-18
2021-05-18
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable T_CLIENT_ID resolves to 00000031-B081-4E97-9437-F20CF874F857
MPRINT(MEQUIBEHSCOREUPRE):   select COALESCE(sum(abc.step_sum),0) into :SumLoans_12m from RTDM_ABT.ABT_CONTRACT abc where abc.CLIENT_ID = "00000031-B081-4E97-9437-F20CF874F857" and 
abc.CONTRACT_BEGINDATE - today() <= 360 and abc.DML_FLAG NE 1;
  175369 1621341661 no_name 0 SQL (503
SQLSRV_39799: Prepared: on connection 0 175370 1621341661 no_name 0 SQL (503
SELECT * FROM  rtdm_abt . ABT_CONTRACT  175371 1621341661 no_name 0 SQL (503
  175372 1621341661 no_name 0 SQL (503
SAS_SQL:  Unable to convert the query to a DBMS specific SQL statement due to an error.  175373 1621341661 no_name 0 SQL (503
ACCESS ENGINE:  SQL statement was not passed to the DBMS, SAS will do the processing.  175374 1621341661 no_name 0 SQL (503
```

Comment: Why the `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Hooked from the test script, thanks for the remark. But this does not solve the mistake:

Comment: Why are you using a DATE value (number of days)  in your WHERE when your question mentions DATETIME values (number of seconds)?

Comment: Your error messages mention a macro variable named TODAY that is not in the code you posted.  Perhaps you need to show more of the log so the error messages are seen in context.

Comment: What you've shown so far is just that SQL can't read `today()` so SAS takes care of it (That's to be expected).  Are you getting an error?  Or just these bits, but it's executing? Is it giving no rows?  What's going on?  What values are in the `CONTRACT_BEGINDATE ` field?

Comment: datetime in question this sql  format (field abc.CONTRACT_BEGINDATE ), also I tried to use datepart() for this field, and as you correctly noticed I tried to assign to the variable today. yymmdd10 format.  quit;
  proc sql noprint;

%let today=%sysfunc(today(),yymmdd10.);
%put &today.;

Comment: Did you try using actual datetime values instead of date values?

Comment: @Dmitriy You still haven't answered: what is the actual error you're concerned about? Nothing you've posted in the question suggests an error - just that SAS didn't send the full code to SQL to parse.  You have to include more information here, more of the log to show your actual error or else more clarity on what you're seeing that is concerning you.

Answer (score 0):

Try comparing the datetime variable to a datetime value.  First let's rewrite your expression to make it easier to code.  The comparison `abc.CONTRACT_BEGINDATE - <TODAY> <= 360` is the same as `abc.CONTRACT_BEGINDATE <= 360 + <TODAY>`. So let's make a macro variable that contains that datetime value.

```
%let now_plus_360_days = %sysfunc(intnx(dtday,%sysfunc(datetime()),360)) ;
```

And then use that macro variable in the expression

```
and abc.CONTRACT_BEGINDATE <= &now_plus_360_days
```

Answer (score 0):

```
proc sql noprint;
 select sum(step_sum)
   into :SumLoans_12m
 from
    RTDM_ABT.ABT_CONTRACT abc
    where abc.client_id = "&T_CLIENT_ID"
    and abc.DML_FLAG <> 1
    and datepart(abc.CONTRACT_BEGINDATE) between today() - 365 and today()
 ;
quit;
```

It worked for me, in double it's nice that I came up with it myself))

Answer (score -1):

SAS date values are integers and are the number of days from epoch `01-JAN-1960`.

`TODAY()` returns a SAS data value, an integer *`nnnnn`*.

You are formatting that value as `yymdd10.` which produces a string with construct *`yyyy-mm-dd`*.  (The string is more understandable to humans than the data value *`nnnnn`*.) and assigning that string to macro symbol `today`.  When the symbol is resolved the string is inserted into your step as source code.

So,

```
abc.CONTRACT_BEGINDATE - &today. <= 360
```

becomes

```
abc.CONTRACT_BEGINDATE - 2021-05-18 <= 360
```

You want to resolve the macro symbol in the context of a SAS date literal which is construct *`"dd-mon-yyyy"D`*

Try

```
%let today_literal = "%sysfunc(today(),date11.)"D;
%put &=today_literal;
```

and

```
abc.CONTRACT_BEGINDATE - &today_literal <= 360
```

However, a lot depends on the options of the libname statement for `RDTM_ABT` that you do not show.  You might be required to use pass-through SQL statement in order to get the result you want

```
connect using RDTM_ABT;
select * from connection to RDTM_ABT 
(

... my query in remote database syntax ...

)
```

You could use the remote system functions for today, or construct the query using the appropriate source code for the remote system date literal or string to date conversion functions.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but I still get the same mistake with different options.

Comment: MLOGIC:  %LET (variable name is TODAY_LITERAL)
MLOGIC:  %PUT &=today_literal
:  Macro variable TODAY_LITERAL resolves to "19-MAY-2021"D
TODAY_LITERAL="19-MAY-2021"D
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable T_CLIENT_ID resolves to 00000031-B081-4E97-9437-F20CF874F857
:  Macro variable TODAY_LITERAL resolves to "19-MAY-2021"D
SAS_SQL:  Unable to convert the query to a DBMS specific SQL statement due to an error.  182698 1621429010 no_name 0 SQL (524
ACCESS ENGINE:  SQL statement was not passed to the DBMS, SAS will do the processing.

Comment: What is the LIBNAME statement and remote DB ?

Comment: This options? - (RTDM_ABT > Properties > Options > Engine : SQLSVR)